# Terraform Azure Alert for 5xx except 503

Tags: azure, terraform

Trying to make an alert that is triggered for all 5xx status codes except 503.

This is my alert:

```
locals {
  xxx_alert_status_codes = [500, 501, 502, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 510, 511]
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "xxx-d-ar-yyy-failed" {
  provider            = azurerm.dev
  name                = "yyy-exceptions-alert-dev"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.xxx-d-rg-yyy.name
  scopes              = [ azurerm_linux_web_app.xxx-d-app-yyy ]
  description         = "....."
  severity            = 1

  dynamic "criteria" {
    for_each = local.yyy_alert_status_codes
    content {
      metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Web/sites"
      metric_name      = "Http5xx"
      dimension {
        operator = "Include"
        values = [{HttpStatusCode = criteria.value},{HttpMethod="*"}]
        name = "ALERT_HPPP${criteria.value}_ERROR"
      }
      aggregation      = "Total"
      operator         = "GreaterThan"
      threshold        = 0      
    }
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.xxx-d-ag-yyy.id
  }
}
```

The error is: Inappropriate value for attribute "values": element 0: string required.

I also tried the dimension block like this:

```
      dimension {
        HttpStatusCode = criteria.value
        HttpMethod="*"
        operator = "Include"
        values = ["*"]
        name = "ALERT_HPPP${criteria.value}_ERROR"
      }
```

It yielded this error message: Unsupporter argument "HttpMethod".

Anyone have an idea of what I should do?
I do not want to make separate alert blocks for each status code.
Is it possible?

Comment: HttpMethod="*" is not part of azurrm monitor metrics alert block, Refer here- A dimension block supports the following:

name - (Required) One of the dimension names.
operator - (Required) The dimension operator. Possible values are Include, Exclude and StartsWith.
values - (Required) The list of dimension values. Refer this official terraform document- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_metric_alert#dimension

Comment: Also, Refer this sample terraform code in the answers for azurrm monitoring metrics -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65437709/how-to-create-different-metric-type-alerts-for-multiple-resources-of-same-resour

Comment: Also, Try this in values block -values = ["{HttpStatusCode = ${criteria.value}}","{HttpMethod=*}"] and remove HttpMethod="*" and add dimension {
  operator = "Include"
  values = ["{HttpStatusCode = ${criteria.value}}"]
  name = "ALERT_HPPP${criteria.value}_ERROR"
}

Comment: We ended up solving this in a different way, by not throwing HTTP-503 but in stead HTTP-429, and then I could just create one alert for all 5xx, without any dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Your string error will go away if you fix your "values" row like this:

```hcl
values = ["HttpStatusCode=\"${criteria.value}\",HttpMethod=\"*\""]
```

The issue was that you tried to use string interpolation incorrectly.

Please note that I'm not sure that this will enable you to deploy what you want, because I'm suspecting other errors down the road. But regardless, this error will be resolved by the code I gave you: `Inappropriate value for attribute "values": element 0: string required.`